# Struts maxfilesize throwing 400 error. How to make it throw a 200 error?

Tags: java, struts2

I have set the following in struts.xml to limit the filesize of uploaded files to 10MB:

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="10485760" />
```

This works like a charm, as it throws a 400 BAD REQUEST when the uploaded file exceeds 10MB.

My problem is that I use the JQuery Form plugin to do the submit of the file upload form. This works by submitting the form in a iFrame, to simulate an ajax submit. This works in all browsers except IE7/IE8. Here, IE can't detect the error, and therefore for all other errors I have resolved to throwing a 200 OK and handling the error in the success-callback at the client side. Not a pretty solution REST-vice, but it works.

The question is then: How can I make struts return a 200 code for this case?

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a filter that wraps the response that gets given to the commons filuepload servlet. In the HttpServletResponse.setStatus/sendError etc methods replace attempts to set to set 400 with 200. You could if you want only do this custom stuff if the user agent reports the browser is IE.